# Using 'callback' and 'updateSystem' to Update Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, callback, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have written the following code the plot the height of water in a tank vs. time.

```
A_t = 16;
[h1, t1] = update_plot(A_t);

f = figure;
h = plot(t1, h1);

b = uicontrol('Parent',f,'Style','slider','Position',[81,54,419,23], 'value',A_t, 'min',14, 'max',17);
bgcolor = f.Color;

set(b,'Callback',@(es,ed) updateSystem(h,update_plot((es.Value))))
```

The function to update the `h` (height of water) and `t` (time) vectors is:

```
function [h1, t1] = update_plot(A_t)
t = 0:0.01:100;
h = zeros(1, length(t)); 
h_init = 20;
t_0 = 0;
myeps = 1e-5;
i = 1;
h(1) = h_init;

while h(i) > myeps
    i = i + 1;
    h(i) = (sqrt(h_init) - (0.18/A_t)*sqrt(981/2)*(t(i) - t_0))^2;

h1 = h(1:i);
t1 = t(1:i);
end
```

The parameter `A_t` is the variable for which I want to use a slider.
**I cannot get the callback function to work.**
I want the plot to be updated as I move the slider.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Quite well written first question (+1). Only thing you could keep in mind is to write variable names as such. You can use the `-sign as an environment to get the "code modus". And for your question: Have you checked if your function does the right thing for different A_t values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
set(b,'Callback', @slider_callback);

function slider_callback(hObject, callbackdata)
    A_t = num2str(hObject.Value);
    update_plot(A_t);
end
```

Then you would also have to clear your figure with `cla` and use `plot` with the update values.

Comment: Hi, I got it working. But now I'm not sure how I can display the value of the slider in a box.

Comment: Also, is it possible to link the text box and the slider, so that when I input a value in the box, the slider goes to that position and the plot is updated?

Comment: You need to change the callback functions so that they update the value of the other element in their own callback function. You need to create a structure of handles first using `guihandles` in order to be able to set these values.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The modified code and functions are:

```
function[f] = update_plot(A_t)
t = 0:0.01:100;
h = zeros(1, length(t)); 
h_init = 20;
t_0 = 0;
myeps = 1e-5;
i = 1;
h(1) = h_init;

while h(i) > myeps
    i = i + 1;
    h(i) = (sqrt(h_init) - (0.18/A_t)*sqrt(981/2)*(t(i) - t_0))^2;

h1 = h(1:i);
t1 = t(1:i);
end
f = plot(t1, h1);
legend('Measured', 'Tuned')
grid on
```

The callback function is:

```
function change_plot(objHandle, ~)
slider_value = get(objHandle, 'Value');
new_A_t = slider_value;
update_plot(new_A_t);
```

And the main function is:

```
A_t = 15.5;

ff = figure;
axes('Parent',ff, 'units', 'normalized',...
    'position',[0.05 0.15  0.9 0.8])

update_plot(A_t);

b = uicontrol('Parent',ff,'Style','slider',...
    'value',A_t, 'min',14, 'max',17,...
    'units', 'normalized',...
    'position', [0.33 0 0.4 0.1],...
    'SliderStep', [0.001 0.1],...
    'callback', @change_plot);

disp_h = uicontrol('style', 'edit',...
    'units', 'normalized',...
    'position', [0.15 0.05 0.15 0.05]);


bgcolor = ff.Color;
```

Now I want to display the value of the slider in the 'edit' box I've created, but so far have been unable to get it to work.